# How to add a custom badge on my product image on a single product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I've tried this code and it worked. But I don't want to add badge "before_add_to_cart_button" hook. Other hooks doesn't work, badge doesn't pop up. I want to add it **"before_single_product_summary"** but it doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_new_badge_single_product_page', 3 );         
function my_new_badge_single_product_page() {
   global $product;
   $newness_days = 30;
   $created = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );
   if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created) {
      echo '<span class="itsnew">' . esc_html__( 'New!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
   }
}
```

I also tried to move my badge when I used **"before_single_product_summary"** hook via css but it doesn't pop up

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_product_block( $html, $data, $product ) {
    global $product;
    $newness_days = 30;
    $html = '<li class="wc-block-grid__product">';
    if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created) {
    $html .= '<div class="image-wrap"><span class="itsnew">' . esc_html__( 'New!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>
            <a href="' . $data->permalink . '" class="wc-block-grid__product-link">' . $data->image . '</a>
            ' . $data->button . '
        </div>
        <h3><a href="' . $data->permalink . '">' . $data->title . '</a></h3>
        ' . $data->badge . '
        ' . $data->price . '
        ' . $data->rating . '
    ';
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= '<div class="image-wrap">
            <a href="' . $data->permalink . '" class="wc-block-grid__product-link">' . $data->image . '</a>
            ' . $data->button . '
        </div>
        <h3><a href="' . $data->permalink . '">' . $data->title . '</a></h3>
        ' . $data->badge . '
        ' . $data->price . '
        ' . $data->rating . '
    ';
    }
    $html .= '</li>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'my_product_block', 10, 3);
```

Comment: what if some products have special features like( flagship store/ flipkart assure for example), that don't fall under specific category, is there any way for that?